# Creating n-tiered with MVC 4 & EF 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on creating n-tiered application where I will have two separate project

```
1) project EF (where it will have all my edmx...)
2) project MVC 4 (internet application.)
```

In my EF i have, I have my `.edmx` file and it generate couple of classes with all props as show below (as sample)...

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public partial class Requester
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        <//more...........>
    }
```

everything is good so far!!

`Back to MVC project`

Now I will be creating a new Controller in my MVC project and when I'm trying to create `Scaffolding` and provide the `Controller` name and `Controller` expects a `Model` so the real question is:

What `Model` should I be passing here?
should I have the same class that EF created? or should I be creating another `Model` in my 'Model Folder` (MVC) and bind it? if yes than am I not creating duplicate property if I go ahead and create my same Model in MVC model Folder project?

What I'm trying to do? : Well my purpose of this exercise is to have my Data Access Layer (DAL) totally separate from MVC project.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to create a view model so you can decorate the properties with view related stuff (i.e. UIHint). Also, this view model will be a reduced version of the class (for example, it can contain just the id of a related object instead of the whole object) making it easier for using as action parameters.

Also, you are talking about objects here, try not to think about "Data".

Answer (score 1):

MVC really needs to be renamed VMVC - ViewModel View Controller.

The models in MVC have nothing to do with EF, Persistence, or your domain. They are a composition of multiple sources of data/settings/things which are represented/required in the View.

So create new View Models for your Views.

***Edit:***

All examples/tutorials which use EF Code First Models as View Models, are terrible tutorials / examples. They teach you bad practice because in the real world, you would never, and should never use those directly in your view.

The ViewModel is a composition or aggregation of data that's going into your view. For example:

If you had a product detail page, you might get the Product information from the Database, the availability of the product from a Web Service, your Shopping Cart from some Cache.

These would be composed into a ViewModel which represents the View that you're displaying. And rendered.

ViewModels should not be shared between views because if you change a ViewModel you change the meaning of the views that share that View Model.

Comment: I'm confused as to what Model role is playing here and what I have seen so far in examples/screen cast is creating `Code First` approach. Can you elaborate little bit more on your answer related to View Models? I have `Schema First` approach since I'm working on enterprise application.